# AppleScript Automator back-compatibility

Tags: applescript, automator

I made a little, easy AppleScript and used Automator to launch it on click:

```
tell application "Terminal"
do script "myScript"
end tell
```

What about back-compatibility? Can I run it on every previous Mac OS X? Will it work?

Comment: Here's Apple page from 2007 using `do shell script` command: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/work_with_as.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001568-BABEBGCF So I think it will work in the previous OS X ;)

Comment: Ok, but in 2007 there was Automator?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software) 2005

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software) first release was 2005, but I would never assume compatibility for any process on any OS older than 10.7

Comment: 10.7 would be absolutely fine

Comment: Then it's more down to what is in the terminal script. For instance, something as seemingly simple as flushing the DNS cache needs different commands depending on OS - see http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/20/flush-dns-cache-mac-os-x/